# How to populate a 2D array of characters without defining the elements?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I wish to make a 2D char array for a “robot arena” with the size being given.

I have two functions, getY and getX that return (int) the x and y maximum coordinates of the arena, i.e size 30 by 10, I want to make horizontal walls ‘-‘, vertical walls’|’ and diagonal walls at the 4 edges ‘/‘ for bottom right and top left corner, and ‘\’ for bottom left and top right corner. All other elements can be whitespace.

I have tried using nested for loops but it just comes out wrong. Thank you

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class GenerateBoard {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int xRow = 10;
    int yCol = 10;
    char[][] board = new char [xRow][yCol];

    for(int x = 0; x < xRow; x++) {
      for(int y = 0; y < yCol; y++) {
        if (x == 0 || x==(xRow-1))  // Sets top and bottom rows to -
            board[x][y] = '-';
        else if (y == 0 || y==(yCol-1)) // Sets left and right rows to |
          board[x][y] = '|';
        else
            board[x][y] = ' ';  // Fills other spaces with ' '
      }
    }

    board[0][0] = '/';  //Top left
    board[0][yCol-1] = '\\';  //Bottom Left
    board[xRow-1][0] = '\\'; //Top right
    board[xRow-1][yCol-1] = '/'; //Bottom Right

    //Print Board
    for(int x = 0; x < xRow; x++) {
      for(int y = 0; y < yCol; y++) {
        System.out.print(board[x][y]);
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
/--------\
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
\--------/
```